# Selenium: Xpath returning blank text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

So I have this url:

https://www.amazon.com/RevitaLash-Cosmetics-RevitaBrow-Advanced-Conditioner/product-reviews/B009QZCAM6/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews

and I wanted to scrape the ratings given by each review but it's not returning anything even when I tried a few xpath variations.

The xpaths do find the 10 elements with the text "x out of 5 stars" when I search it in the page with the given xpath and here is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver


chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

url = https://www.amazon.com/RevitaLash-Cosmetics-RevitaBrow-Advanced-Conditioner/product-reviews/B009QZCAM6/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews

driver.get(url)

ratings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none review-views celwidget"]//div[@class="a-row"]/a[@class="a-link-normal"]/i/span')
#ratings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/*//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//i[@data-hook="review-star-rating"]/span[@class="a-icon-alt"]')
#ratings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/*//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//i[@data-hook="review-star-rating"]/span')

rating_row = []
for rating in ratings:
    rating_row.append(rating.text)
```

but when I call rating_row it just ends up returning list of blank texts when I call rating_row

```
> rating_row
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I solve this?
This result is the same for other urls that contain other reviews as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below **xpath**  :

```
//i[@data-hook='review-star-rating']/span
```

in code  :

```
rating_row = []
for rating in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//i[@data-hook='review-star-rating']/span"):
    rating_row.append(rating.text)
```

I would recommend you to have `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` implicit wait also. You can write this at this place :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Read more about [Implicit wait here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits)

Comment: thank you! changing it to "//i[@data-hook='review-star-rating']/span" worked! Do you mind explaining why this worked and not my xpath if that's okay with you?

Comment: Your xpath `//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none review-views celwidget"]//div[@class="a-row"]/a[@class="a-link-normal"]/i/span` does represent all those 10 entry, having said that I see you are using class name with spaces which I feel would be more complex to parse as compare to `//i[@data-hook='review-star-rating']/span`, it just kinda bit sort and more readable. the processor does not have to look for classes, the again classes and then a tag then i, with my solution it would directly look for i and span.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line `rating_row.append(rating.text)` with `rating_row.append(rating.get_attribute('innerHTML'))`